# Not sure how I see my bitcoin balance

Tags: balance, utxo-set

Ok so in 2018 I purchased $1500 worth of bitcoin through Coinspot and transferred most of it - well the keys to it of course - onto a Ledger. Since then Bitcoin has moved up a decent amount so I know the $1200 still sitting on Coinspot reflects the Bitcoin I left there.

I haven't touched or moved anything since then but want to see what the value is of my bitcoin that I moved to offline.

I know the ledger doesn't actually contains coins and all that stuff, I'd just like a simple method to see how much bitcoin I own right now.

I'm probably missing something very obvious but would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember what proportion of coins was sent to the ledger versus stored on Coinspot? If so, you can work it out based on the increase in price of the remaining amount. You could perhaps find an old email or something with the details of the purchase, or look on Coinspot at your transaction history, to see how much you bought and moved to the ledger.

Otherwise, you could plug your ledger in and check the balance through its software.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the answer. I suspect it was like 80% but I just want to some peace of mind. OK so once I get the ledger "open" (forgot my pin but have my 24 words phrase) then it will be able to display the value of the coins sent to the ledger? Thats awesome thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll have to plug it into a computer to allow it to access the internet I think.